# HTML2PDF - Input Forms Are Editable, Don't WAnt Them To Be

Tags: php, html, forms, pdf, html2pdf

I'm using HTML2PDF ( http://www.html2pdf.fr/en ) library for PHP to convert a CSS/xHTML page to a PDF file (it works).

However, the HTML form's  tags are being converted to editable form fiends in the downloaded PDF (meaning the user can change these fields and re-save the PDF).  Allowing them to edit these fields is dangerous.  The main reason for using the  tags in the first place is to get checkboxes/radio buttons next to important fields that are pulled from the database.

Is there any way to keep the checkbox/radio button/form functionality but DISABLE, or disallow users to be able, any way to edit them?

..or is the only way to create a CSS style (or image element) that contains these checked/unchecked boxes and print our  text to the PDF directly rather than through an  tag?

```
Does your employer offer Affordable/Adequate healthcare? 
<input type="radio" name="iscoverage" checked="<?php echo $data['iscoverage']=='Y' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>" value='Y' />&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="iscoverage"  checked="<?php echo ($data['iscoverage']=='N' ? 'checked' : ''); ?>" value='N' />
```

UDATES:

The suggested help from comments did not provide me any solution (though, it was a very good idea that I had not considered).

I've transferred all of these inputs to echo'd output for the time being (with CSS sprites as the radio buttons/check boxes).  However, I'd still like to utilize the form elements as there will be cases in the future where these PDF's should be editable (ie, via administrators).

Many thanks!

Comment: What happens when you [disable the controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/radio#a-disabled) and then convert?

Comment: @admdrew - Using the <radiogroup> as in the example does not display anything and forces the PDF to print to the page rather than download.  Adding 'disabled="true"' to the '<input type="radio">' looks lovely (and works great) when printed to the screen in HTML but does not work (users can still change/edit it) when converted to a downloadable PDF.

Comment: Dang, sorry. That's about the only thing I could think of.

Comment: How about adding 'disabled="disabled"' ?

Comment: @SanderKoedood - I tried that as well, during testing of admdrew's suggestion with the results.

Answer (score -1):

I found the correct answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096900/textarea-and-input-text-is-editable-when-using-html2pdf-plugin)

```php
$html2pdf->pdf->SetProtection(array('print','modify', 'annot-forms'));
```

It will set the pdf's permission to only allow copying and printing of the content, the pdf won't be editable and forms/annotations disabled

More info on the [html2pdf documentation](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/tcpdf_methods.md#document-protection)