# Textarea and input text is editable when using HTML2PDF plugin

Tags: php, laravel-4, html2pdf

I am using HTL2PDF plugin .

My problem is the Texarea and PDF is all editable in PDF that I recieve

My code is as follow

```
require_once(app_path().'/libs/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');

        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en');



        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');



        $html2pdf->WriteHTML($html22);



        $htmltosend=$html2pdf->Output('','S');
```

is there a way I can stop it from converting into editable PDF

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create the PDF, but it should not be editable? Use `SetProtection` like:

```
$html2pdf->pdf->SetProtection(array('print'), '');
```

You can find further information at http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:protect.
If you use an empty permissions array, only viewing but not even printing will be allowed. Possible values for the permissions are:

> - copy: copy text and images to the clipboard
> - print: print the document
> - modify: modify it (except for annotations and forms)
> - annot-forms: add annotations and forms

Comment: bro I guess SetProtection is to add password to the PDF not to make it uneditable

Comment: Sorry that I did not include the reference, I now have added it to the answer. If you do not set a password, it will not ask for it, but still limit access.

Comment: Thanks For the link I did that but now all the content of textarea and Input types are not visible on Windows and becomes visible on Mac when I click on them