# How do I make a fillable form with HTML2PDF?

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, html2pdf

I'm trying to allow my users to generate a custom PDF with reflection opportunities (text fields) and checkboxes to allow them to complete tasks.

I'm using HTML2PDF to convert my content into a PDF. My understanding is that this should happen automatically if I use  tags, as I've seen [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206235/html2pdf-input-forms-are-editable-dont-want-them-to-be) asking how to turn this off. But for me, it's not fillable.

I have a very basic example [here](https://codepen.io/arendr/pen/MWQddYO).

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-GsLlZN/3F2ErC5ifS5QtgpiJtWd43JWSuIgh7mbzZ8zBps+dvLusV+eNQATqgA/HdeKFVgA5v3S/cIrLF7QnIg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
    <form>
      <input type="text">
      <br>
      <label for="checkbox">Check me</label><input type="checkbox">
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Button to generate PDF. -->
  <button id="btnTest">Download My Journal</button>
</body>
<script>
  function test() {
    var element = document.getElementById('root');
    html2pdf(element);
  }
  document.getElementById('btnTest').onclick = test;
</script>

</html>
```

Am I missing something about how forms and/or fillable PDFs work?

Comment: @K J, did you click the download button on the Codepen and open the pdf file?

Comment: Edit: I just noticed that the StackOverflow link I posted is for a different library even though it has the same name. I will need to do some more playing around with this.